# Adware on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm getting adware on Chrome that opens up new tabs when I click on certain areas of legitimate websites such as this one. I'm on Ubuntu 14 and Chrome 44. How do I remove it?

Comment: Tried purging and reinstalling chrome ?  there's also hidden config folders for chrome in your home directory (forget which one it is, i haven't used chrome in a long time ), you might want to try deleting everything there

Comment: @Serg
/home/USERNAME/.config/chromium/Default
or
/home/USERNAME/.config/google-chrome/Default 

If you delete the contents of the Default directory, it basically makes Chrome/Chromium as if it were a new install. You will have to sign in again to get your bookmarks or re-import them from a backup. I would back up the Default directory just to be on the safe side before deleting. 

I assume you've already tried uninstalling the extension and re-installing in: chrome://extensions

Comment: Did you look for any unwanted browser plug ins, may have been installed automatically on some bad sites

Comment: Is this considered on topic?

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of installation of the bad adware plugin?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I would install http://www.clamav.net/downloads for Ubuntu. Also chrome on Ubuntu has add-ons this can be found in the settings tab. I would install a pop-up blocker this will stop websites from opening new tabs. Steps go to terminal CTLT+ALT+T Remove chrome `sudo apt-get purge chrome` Install clamav `sudo apt-get install clamav`(or use provided website/software center) Install chrome `sudo apt-get install chrome` Run updates for all programs `sudo apt-get upgrade` Launch Clamav and run scan! Launch chrome install pop-up blocker in add-ons under settings.

Answer (score 0):

A/ sorry, delete/reboot etc are not useful. the command for clam is also incorrect. users should go to the clam site and seek instructions. the terminal command is "clamscan". to use this, you need to have online access to the daily definitions - I cannot, so I download from the clam site. good luck trying to disinfect, as no AV app is 100% effective. if infected with malware, the best course is to wipe and reinstall your system.

B/ to remove adware. a reinstall is useless, as the adware infects your profile. simple to remove. in Chromium, do: settings/ advanced/ reset settings.  this should clear adware. if not, you have malware.  next, install the extension "chrome adware remover".

hope this helps.